# VBA thinks Return is a variable

Tags: vba, function, fibonacci

I was trying to make fibonacci in a recursive way like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim n, contador, termo

function fibonacci(n)
  if n < 2 then
    Return n
  else
    Return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
  end if        
End function

termo = InputBox("Diga ate que termo vai a sequencia de fibonacci")*1

for contador = 0 to termo
  MsgBox fibonacci(contador)
next
```

But I am getting the error: Variable not defined: 'Return'
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `Return` isn't used in VBA

Comment: @TimWilliams *shouldn't be*. I hope it's not used anymore. Truly.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified *in that context*  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A VBA function's return value isn't returned with the `Return` keyword.

In fact, the only valid usage of `Return` as a keyword is to return from a `GoSub` jump:

```
    foo = 42
    GoSub DoSomething
    Debug.Print foo

DoSomething:
    foo = foo / 2
    Return
```

The `GoSub` jumps to the `DoSomething` label, divides `foo` by 2 and *returns* to the calling subroutine, to output 21 to the debug/immediate pane.

An archaic keyword and construct that predates the introduction of actual `Sub` and `Function` constructs.

So how does a function return then?

By... (hold your breath and pinch your nose) ... *assigning to the function's identifier*:

```
Function GetFoo() As Integer
    GetFoo = 42
End Function
```

Same for property getters:

```
Property Get Foo() As Integer
    Foo = 42
End Property
```

The best part? Doing that doesn't *return*. It determines the *return value*. If you need to exit immediately (say, because there's other code that would run otherwise), you need to use `Exit Function`.

```
Function GetFoo() As Integer
    GetFoo = 42
    Exit Function
    Debug.Print "dead code here"
End Function
```

Comment: (hold your breath and pinch your nose) . LOL +1

Comment: Wow, that `GoSub` brought back memories of 25 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to return the value of the function, you would set that value to the name of the function like below:

```
function fibonacci(n)
  if n < 2 then
    fibonacci = n
  else
    fibonacci = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
  end if        
End function
```

Your function has a logical error though, your for loop is returning termo + 1 elements because you are including elements 0, 1, 2, and 3. So you could set your for loop to go from 0 to termo-1.

Answer (score 0):

Change to...

```
Function fibonacci(n)
    If n < 1 Then
        fibonacci = n
    Else
        fibonacci = n + fibonacci(n - 1)
    End if        
End Function
```